# Make lodash typings' defaultTo method compatible with TypeScript compiler's strictNullChecks

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-typings

I encountered this problem using TypeScript and Lodash's typing ([@types/lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash)).

If I enable `strictNullChecks` in TypeScript's compiler options. The code below will result in error.

```ts
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts" />

const foo = (myString?: string) => {
    return _.defaultTo(myString, 'defaultString');
}
```

> index.ts(4,28): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '"defaultString" | null | undefined'.
>     Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"defaultString" | null | undefined'.

If I understood it correctly, it's because the `_.defaultTo` expects the first paramter to be type of `T | null | undefined`, while variable myString is an optional string (i.e string or undefined).

Above is just a simple demo case, where I can of course validate the string using ternary operator/if statement. In real world project, I have been using `_.defaultTo` all over the place for different types.

Just wondering if there is way to use `_.defaultTo` and `strictNullChecks` at the same time?

FYI, null and undefined were added to `_defaultTo` method here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/15895/files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in TypeScript - it fails to find common type for `value` and `defaultValue` and just uses the type of `defaultValue` for `T` if `defaultTo` is declared as

```
defaultTo<T>(value: T | null | undefined, defaultValue: T): T;
```

The workaround is to allow `undefined` for second parameter (`null` will also work):

```
defaultTo<T>(value: T | null | undefined, defaultValue: T | undefined): T | undefined;
```